# how to bring the choose.file() dialog to the foreground

Tags: user-interface, r, dialog

I'm using the function `choose.dir()` in a script that is run with rscript.exe under Windows XP. The problem is that the directory choosing dialog does not pop up as a top-level window. How can I bring the dialogue to the foreground?

In the meantime, I solved my problem by using visual basic script. Of course, this only works with windows:

```
tf <- tempfile(fileext = '.vbs')
cat('Set folder = CreateObject("Shell.Application") _
        .BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder" _
       , &H0001, 17)
       Wscript.Echo folder.Self.Path
', file = tf)
tail(shell(paste('Cscript', tf), intern = T), 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the **vbs** solution! I have the same problem for `choose.file()`. Can you offer **vbs** code for this?

Answer (score 1):

After searching the rhelp archives it appears the answer is that you can't use `choose.dir` and `file.choose` in a non-interactive session. You might be able to do something similar, since `list.files`, `file.info`, `file.access` and `files` can be used to gather information, you can display this by writing to a graphics device and executing a system() call to get it displayed, and readLines can be used to get user input.